# Probability of intersecting a rectangle with random straight lines

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, algorithms, computational-geometry

We are given a rectangle $R$ with sides lengths $r_1$ and $r_2$, contained in a square $S$, with sides lengths $s_1=s_2\ge r_1$ and $s_2=s_1\ge r_2$. $R$ and $S$ are axis-aligned in a cartesian plane $P$. With the following recursive random process, we select straight lines orthogonal to the sides of $R$ (and $S$), until $R$ is cut.

At each time step, we select one of the two axes of $P$ with probability $\tfrac12$. Let $a$ the axis selected. Thereafter a straight line $L$ is selected uniformly at random from the ones cutting $S$ and orthogonal to $a$. Let $S'$ and $S''$ be the two parts of $S$ generated by the cut of $L$. These two random steps are repeated until $R$ is cut by $L$, and each time $R$ is not cut, $S$ is transformed by removing its part (either $S'$ or $S''$) that does *not* contain $R$.

---

**Question:** Given the coordinates of the vertices of $R$ providing its position within $S$, what is the probability $p_i$ that it is eventually cut (at the end of the random process) by a line orthogonal to its sides with length $r_i$ for $i\in\{1,2\}$?

(For the sake of clarity, we obviously have $p_1=1-p_2$.).

Comment: If you put the rectangle in the lower left hand corner, as in J O'Rourke's first picture, the process of cutting either side by itself is the well-known stick breaking process.  The number of tries until you cut the side on the y axis is about -log(r_1/s_1), and similarly for the side on the x axis.  It seems to me that the probability of hitting one side first is likely to depend on  those quantities.  I haven't tried to make a proof out of this.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @mike. I see your point. Would you have any suggestion about what happens then when the rectangle is *not* positioned in a corner of the square?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if the probability is dependent only on $r_i$, or also dependent on
the placement of $R$ within $S$?
In these two examples,

---

[image]

---

it takes an average of $2.70$ steps to reach slicing $R$ on the left, but
$3.16$ steps on the right.

I realize I'm ignoring your condition that $s_i \gg r_i$.

---

**Added 4Aug2020**.
I include below some simulation data that might help a theoretical investigation.
Here are two examples where $R = 0.2 \times 0.1$ in a unit square $S$.

---

[image]

---

On the left, after one million trials, the probability that the long
side of $R$ is sliced was $0.591$.
On the right, the probability was $0.622$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Joseph. In my opinion the required probability is independent of the placement of $R$ within $S$, and is independent of the number of time steps to reach slicing R, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Furthermore, if the conjecture is true, an interesting generalization would be to extend it when $S$ is not a square, and it is a rectangle. In this case I think that we can obtain the same result if the probabilities to choose an axis at each time step are $\frac{s_i}{s_1+s_2}$ for $i\in\{1,2\}$, instead of $\tfrac12$.

Comment: @PenelopeBenenati: One aspect I don't understand. The probability of slicing $R$ is $1$: Eventually it will occur. So do you mean by "the probability," the probability that $R$ is cut on any given step? If so, then this depends on the number of steps.

Comment: @PenelopeBenenati: Re $S$ a rectangle: $S$ is a rectangle after the first step.

Comment: By writing "probability" in my comment, I mean the probability required in the problem question, namely "the probability that $R$ is sliced by a line orthogonal to its edges with length $r_i$", which I conjecture to be equal to $\frac{r_i}{\sum_i r_i}$.

Comment: Yes, $S$ is a.s. a rectangle after the first step, but I conjecture that ***only*** the shape of $S$ at time step $t=0$  matters, because all the probabilities for the events occurring a time $t\ge1$ are conditioned on the first cut(s) selected.

Comment: Starting from a very simple example, consider the special case where $r_1=s_1$ (forgetting for a moment the condition $s_1\gg r_1$ in the problem text, which I just changed because I am interesting in the more general setting where $r_1\le s_1$ and $r_2\le s_2$), and $r_2 < s_2$. Is it true in this specific case that the probability that $R$ is sliced by a line orthogonal to the edges with length $r_1$  (respectively $r_2$) is $\frac{r_1}{r_1+r_2}$ (respectively $\frac{r_2}{r_1+r_2}$)?

Comment: @PenelopeBenenati: I think I finally understand your question. $R$ will eventually be cut. You are seeking the probability that it is cut on the long side vs the short side, the $r_1$ side vs the $r_2$ side.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Joseph, yes, this is exactly what I meant. Do you think I should rephrase the question in the problem text, because it is not sufficiently clear? I accept any suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: @PenelopeBenenati: Ignoring the $s_i \gg r_i$ condition, simulations suggest: (1) the conjecture is not precisely true; (2) the probability depends on the position of $R$ within $S$. But (a) this is from simulations, and (b) still your conjecture may hold for $s_i \gg r_i$.

Comment: [The software is saying the comments should cease.]

Comment: Thank you again Joseph for your comments. Based on them I have now rephrased the question, which is finally much more significant.